# Rdieharder text file as input

Tags: r, random, rstudio

## Summary

I'm trying to test an RNG which generates numbers to a text file, ideally using decimal numbers between 0 and 1. This using the Rdieharder package.(Note this is my first time using R or any rng test for that matter)

## Trying

I am aware of the existence of rng = file_input and file_input_raw functions. All my attempts to run binary or decimal numbers in text files through them has been unsuccessful. Either resulting in fatal errors which freeze Rstudio or as following (image).

[image: Plot binary attempt]

## Code

My attempts look like this in Rstudio.

```
library(RDieHarder)
library(random)

dh <- dieharder(rng = "file_input_raw", inputfile = "Random.txt")

plot(dh)
```

I have tried different approaches to formatting the text file.

### Binary

```
32 bit binary numbers as follows:
111000010100001100011011110010
1110000100111111011001011011001
11100001001110111001100100100111
111111101001011010100100000111
....
2,500,000 numbers
```

This results in following

[image: Plot binary attempt]

This seems like the program recognizes my input as being 0.

### Decimal

```
0.667371
0.673781
0.663682
0.684186
0.642766
0.726927
0.556512
...
1000 numbers
```

This freezes Rstudio for both "file_input" and "file_input_raw".

The numbers aren't indicative of final results For the moment I am just trying to get a meaningful result from dieharder. Is my formatting wrong or do I need a different rng= ? Or does anyone know a simple way to use rdieharder on a text file ?

Comment: This is enough: `dh <- dieharder(inputfile =  "Random.txt")`. Argument `rng` must be one of `dieharderGenerators()`, either a character string (column `names`) or the `id` number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following instructions work as expected. It is a matter of passing only the file name in `dieharder()` argument `inputfile`.

Create test data.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible
r <- runif(1000)
f <- file("Random.txt", open = "wt")
writeLines(as.character(r), con = f)
close(f)
```

Now test for randomness.

```
dh <- dieharder(inputfile =  "Random.txt")

plot(dh)
```

[image]

Comment: somehow it gives different results each time we repeat the function LOL

Comment: @Enderphan If every time you run the code you first set the pseudo-RNG state with `set.seed(1234)` you will get the same results.

Comment: I ran it as a default that was the reason. Now I tried to intialize the "rng" along with "inputfile" then it worked perfectly. However, we can't set the tsamples in this library. In the "dieharder" terminal tool, it gives 02 results for the diehard_runs test but in R it gives only one.

Comment: @Enderphan That relates to different user interfaces to the DieHarder suite, have you read the package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RDieHarder/vignettes/RDieHarder.pdf)?

Comment: Yes, went thru that. In the end, the results given by these 02 tools should be identical, though. I've tried to run the Diehard_runs test, which had the same psamples, tsamples, ntulp value but the given results were different. Should the input file have the same format header like the Dieharder test suite one (type, count, numbit)? or just a sequence of the raw integers? Thanks

Comment: @Enderphan I don't know what to answer to that question, your best option is to contact `maintainer("RDieHarder")`.